# Is it possible to add a tag to AWS AMI created with Packer containing name of filtered source_ami?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, packer

I am building AWS AMI with *Packer*. The source image is defined by filter `source_ami_filter` and the source block looks like

```
source "amazon-ebs" "test-image" {
  ami_name      = "Some AMI Name"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  region        = "eu-central-1"
  source_ami_filter {
    filters = {
      name                = "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"
      root-device-type    = "ebs"
      virtualization-type = "hvm"
    }
    most_recent = true
    owners      = ["099720109477"]
  }
  tags = {
//    source_ami_name = ...  # how to get it?
  }
  ssh_username = "ubuntu"
}
```

How to get the name of the used source AMI from canonical?

Comment: Did you try using `"source_ami_name": "{{.SourceAMIName}}"`?

Comment: I tried it and it works. Could you please write it as an answer along with a reference to documentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some [shared information variables](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon/ebs#build-shared-information-variables), for instance, [SourceAMIName](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon/ebs#sourceami-1).

That means you can get your source AMI name and use it as a tag by doing this:

```
source_ami_name = "{{ .SourceAMIName }}"
```

Here's a full example: https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon/ebs#tag-example